# backspace not working in macvim shell

Tags: bash, shell, vim, macvim

When I drop into the shell in macvim using the `:shell` command, using the backspace key doesn't delete, instead special characters are inserted as in the screenshot below:

[image: macvim backspace]

I have tried `set nocompatible` in my `.vimrc` but it made no difference.

Any idea how to fix this?

My `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile` is below

```
alias ll='ls -al'
# Set CLICOLOR if you want Ansi Colors in iTerm2
export CLICOLOR=1

# Set colors to match iTerm2 Terminal Colors
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

My `.vimrc` is below:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
execute pathogen#helptags()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set number
set hidden

let mapleader="\<Space>"

" set colour scheme
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized

" NERDTree config
map <F5> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
let NERDTreeIgnore=['^__py.*']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
stty erase <Backspace>
```

When this works, you can add it in your `$HOME/.bashrc`

Comment: When I put that into the bash shell I get `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token newline`

Comment: You shouldn't type the characters of `<Backspace>` but hit the key called `Backspace`. You can also use another char for the Backspace. You could even make the `x` stand for delete with `stty erase x`.