# Backspace doesn't work in python, in VIM's console with bash (on macOS)

Tags: python, vim, encoding, utf-8, backspace

I'm new on StackOverflow, and on VIM, but I really tried to find an answer to my question but found nothing...

I'm on macOS Sierra (latest OS X)

I use MacVim, but the problem is the same if i try on VIM

My backspace works perfectly, every time I need it, in VIM, in bash or in python. Except in that case :

I'm on vim, I try to launch in VIM's console (with :!python) a python program, but when I have to type something, I can't use BackSpace... it writes a ^H (and something as weird as this happens with arrows).
It does the same thing with ipython.
I don't understand how I can make this backspace work specifically in that context ?

In mVIM opened with Conque Term plugin : (But it's the same with :!...)

```
bash-3.2$ ipython Documents/example1.py
Enter a : 2^H^[[A^[[B^[[C^[[D
```

Do note that this doesn't happen when :

- I launch python or ipython directly in bash (not in VIM)
- I launch a program with python or ipython in bash (not in VIM)
- I launch python (not a program, only python) or ipython in VIM's bash

Comment: related ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377438/backspace-not-working-in-macvim-shell

Comment: Vim's shell exec isn't really designed to do interactive sessions, and you're encountering that problem. It's designed to simply run a command, possibly piping some or all of the file to that command, e.g. `:%!sort` and such. You are seeing control codes such as those used by arrow keys, and it just isn't a full terminal emulator, so it doesn't know how to handle that. Use a terminal window for those things.

Comment: Okay.... Thanks for that